# Retrieve the RecordType which are Accessible by Profile only

Tags: apex

I want display the Record types which are accessible by logged in user profile in a VF page dropdown list.
i used the below query, which returns me all types.
and i could find a relationship between profile and recordType objects.Its not mentioned in the ER diagram as well.

**

```
SOQL:
select id,name from RecordType where sobjecttype='task' And isActive=true
```

**

is there any way to Retrieve the RecordType which are Accessible by Profile only.
If not , Please let me know any work arounds if you know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [RecordTypeInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm) methods to determine which record types are available to a user. Start by calling [DescribeSObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfos](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) (or by ID or by name), iterate through each value, calling `isAvailable()` on each. This also automatically handles things like permission sets that a user might have, etc.

Example:

```
List<SelectOption> recordTypes = new List<SelectOption>();
for(RecordTypeInfo info: Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos()) {
    if(info.isAvailable()) {
        recordTypes.add(new SelectOption(info.getRecordTypeId(), info.getName()));
    }
}

// Include these next 3 lines to output the results during development and debugging
for( SelectOption selopt: recordTypes ) {
    System.debug( selopt.getLabel() + ',' + selopt.getValue() );
}
```

Comment: Would give +1 if you had code examples. This is pretty close to a link only answer as is.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. describe call doesnt seems to be working for TASK object. Task.SObjectType.getDescribe();

Comment: @AdrianLarson You're absolutely right. I wasn't thinking. I've added such an example.

Comment: @KrForce I'm guessing you have a variable named "task". Try `Schema.Task.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos()` instead.

Comment: Perfect..works great for me. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Any clue of how to do the same but for any user provided by id, i.e. not just the current one?

Comment: @wesaw You would use the metadata API. I can't put a full solution in a comment, though, so you might want to ask a new question if you're stuck trying to implement your solution.