# Get available record types for any user (not just current one) in apex code

Tags: apex, permissions, profile, record-type

We need to fetch in apex code list of available record types for a user provided by its id.

We've already figured out [how to do the same for current user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/94041) (e.g. using DescribeSObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfos and filter by isAvailable).

But in our case we need to do the same for any user provided by its id, i.e. being in admin user context to fetch available record types for sales rep user etc.