# Get available record types for user in Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, record-type

I want to replicate the "New" action on Opportunity object in a custom action. On Opportunity object i have several record types. Is it possible via a flow to get the available for the user record types and show them to the user in a screen component (radio button component). Or do i need to create a custom component to show available record types for the user and handle the record type selection?
From what i have seen, i can only use the recordChoiceSet that selects all record types... but i want the record types available to the user according to his profile settings. Has anyone found a solution to that to avoid the effort of customization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing out of the box within Flow to accomplish this.

In terms of the custom customizations needed - there's examples online that can help. This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94041/retrieve-the-recordtype-which-are-accessible-by-profile-only) goes over how to get the available record types in Apex. There's, similarly, this [source code](https://github.com/alexed1/LightningFlowComponents/tree/master/flow_action_components/GetRecordTypeInfobyObject) from [unofficialsf](https://unofficialsf.com/get-record-type-info-by-object-flow-action/) that can be specifically combined with a custom component from there called [quickchoice](https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/) which displays information in a picklist/radio button.

Comment: Thank you, Kris! :)